# Host ASP.NET Core in a Windows Service

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a question from official website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

This article is to teach people to publish ASP.NET Core project running as a Windows service.

I think there are 2 parts: one is a worker service project, another is an ASP.NET Core project, this article said you should establish a worker service project.

Then do app configuration, as shown in this screenshot:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I7VB.png)

I think the code included on the image in an ASP.NET Core project, I don't know the relationship between worker service project and ASP.NET Core project, so I have no idea that how to publish the ASP.NET Core project to a Windows service, can anyone tell me something about that?

Comment: There's only one project, not two. The Worker template is used only to show how to create an ASP.NET Core project that also does some background work. What you end up with is an ASP.NET Core application with a hosted service and the `.AddWindowsService()` call

Comment: Hope my following sample can explain it more clearly for you, it still has some issue, like `InvalidOperationException: The view 'Privacy' was not found`. But it's not the main issue in this case, and I will update later if you want.

Comment: After investigating the issue, the below answer will tell you how to deploy the worker service and asp.net core web app to windows  service.

Comment: After testing, it seems to me that there is no difference between the two projects, that is, the worker service adds the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices package and deletes the mvc-related content. The two projects are interchangeable and essentially the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1.The easist way: Create a Asp.net core MVC Project

1.Add `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices` Package

2.Add  `builder.Services.AddWindowsService();` in Program.cs

3.Deploy it as single files and register it as windows service like below, you can find the detailed steps in section2.

[image]

**Tips**

If we deploy it as windows service, it will running on kestrel, it's better to define the port in code.

```
        builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
        {
            serverOptions.ListenAnyIP(5000); // http
        });
```

#### 2. Create a Worker Server Project

Panagiotis Kanavos's comment is right. Worker Service Project is a streamlined project template used in windows services.

**You can follow my steps to make the worker service support mvc and other functions.**

[image]

[image]

1.Create the folders and files like mvc project

2.Add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>dotnet-WorkerService1-d5189c80-2268-4d3c-9c71-bf06594ee612</UserSecretsId>
    <RazorCompileOnPublish>true</RazorCompileOnPublish>
    <RazorCompileOnBuild>true</RazorCompileOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="7.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="7.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
      <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Views\Home\" />
    <Folder Include="Views\Shared\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

3.Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WorkerService1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
            {
                serverOptions.ListenAnyIP(5000); // http
            });

            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
            builder.Services.AddWindowsService();
            builder.Services.AddHostedService<Worker>();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllerRoute(
               name: "default",
               pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            app.Run();

            //IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            //    .ConfigureServices(services =>
            //    {
            //        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();

            //    })
            //    .Build();
            //host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

===UPDATE===

4.Change Project SDK to Web, then we will find the project icon will be changed and we need to reload the project.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>dotnet-WorkerService1-d5189c80-2268-4d3c-9c71-bf06594ee612</UserSecretsId>
    <RazorCompileOnPublish>true</RazorCompileOnPublish>
    <RazorCompileOnBuild>true</RazorCompileOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="7.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="7.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
      <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
    <Folder Include="Views\Home\" />
    <Folder Include="Views\Shared\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

[image]

4.Then we need to [publish the app as a single file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service?pivots=dotnet-7-0#publish-the-app).

[image]

5.[Create the Windows Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service?pivots=dotnet-7-0#create-the-windows-service) and start it manually

[image]

[image]

6.Check the port 5000.

[image]

Comment: Great stuff. 

Comment: "Tips

If we deploy it as windows service, it will running on kestrel, it's better to define the port in code."

Saying why might be nice.

Comment: "Then we need to publish the app as a single file." Again, why?