# OTel: Why kestrel_queued_connections is not exported when asp.net core web api is deployed on IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, open-telemetry, asp.net-core-8, otel

Following [this web page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/log-mon/metrics/metrics?view=aspnetcore-8.0) I can get the kestrel counters when debugging. But when I deploy the project to IIS and open /metrics url in browser, no kestrel counter is listed. Why?

Here is the metrics when debugging. And the most important counter I need is kestrel_queued_connections.

[image: Metrics when debugging]

Answer (score 0):

This [`kestrel.queued_connections`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/built-in-metrics-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-8.0#microsoftaspnetcoreserverkestrel) indicator is for `Kestrel` web server, not for `IIS` web server.

You can verify it via double-click the `.exe` and open the `/metrics` site, then you can see `kestrel_queued_connections` again.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the kestrel.queued_connections indicator is for Kestrel and I can get it if I run the .exe file directly from the /metrics response. But when I deploy it to iis, I cannot get the kestrel indicators in the /metrics response while other indicators are still returned. What I need is the "queued requests" indicator, no matter from perfmon or OTel since the ASP.NET* categories in perfmon does not work for ASP.NET Core projects anymore.

Comment: One more thing, the CurrentQueueSize counter in HTTP Service Request Queues is always 0, even when the active requests is 5000 and next request will get 503 status code immediately, so I think it is not the counter I need. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Hi Jason, there may be some misunderstanding. I can get the kestrel.queued_connections indicator if I run it directly, the problem is if it is hosted on IIS, the indicator won't return. That's the problem. And at the same time, other indicators like http_server_active_requests and aspnetcore_routing_match_attempts_total return always.

Comment: Hi @leonardzheng , I will check it later, please be patient.

Comment: Hi @leonardzheng  I would like to say that if you deploy in IIS, you will usually use Dynatrace to monitor it, and if you want to do it in the way in the post, then we [can deploy it in a windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77444953/7687666).