# Windows Service incorrectly executes utility executable instead of main application in ASP.NET Core 7.0

Tags: c#, windows, asp.net-core, windows-services, asp.net-core-7.0

I encountered an issue while configuring an ASP.NET Core 7.0 web application to run as a Windows Service (Windows 11), following the official Microsoft guide: [Host ASP.NET Core in a Windows Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio)

After setting up the service with sc.exe and specifying the binpath to my application, the service failed to start, timing out without logging any events. Further investigation revealed that the service did not execute any code from Program.cs, as indicated by the absence of startup logs.

Narrowing down the problem involved removing and incrementally adding project dependencies. I discovered the issue was related to the presence of an auxiliary .exe file in the application's source folder. This utility executable's name is a prefix of the main application file, and Windows Services appears to execute this file instead of the intended main application. Upon changing the name of the utility executable to something that is not a prefix of the main application, the service correctly executes the main application:

Example 1:

```
binpath = "<SOURCE FOLDER PATH>\application name.exe"
utility .exe path = "<SOURCE FOLDER PATH>\app.exe"  <--- THIS IS RUN
main .exe path = "<SOURCE FOLDER PATH>\application name.exe"
```

Example 2:

```
binpath = "<SOURCE FOLDER PATH>\application name.exe"
utility .exe path = "<SOURCE FOLDER PATH>\test.exe"  
main .exe path = "<SOURCE FOLDER PATH>\application name.exe" <--- THIS IS RUN
```

**Question**: How does Windows Services determine which executable to run from the specified binpath? Is there a naming convention or selection process that could cause it to choose an auxiliary executable over the main application, to which the binpath directly references?

This problem had me debugging for quite some time, so if everyone runs into an similar issue, I hope this helps!

Comment: [I have written a tutorial before, you can check it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77444953/7687666) Hope it can help you.

Comment: Is it actually like `application name.exe` and `app.exe` or is the shorter name the same as the longer one, *up until a space*?

Comment: @JasonPan I did manage to make it work - this post is just for others that encounter the same issue as I did! But thank you!

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever So the main application was something like ```Domain App Service.exe```, while the utility application was named ```Domain.exe```. The 'bug' also occured when the utility application was named ```Domain App.exe```, i.e. just a longer prefix of the main application.

Comment: Yes, but that points to the system trying to break the command line into an app and some arguments because you've not quoted the string so it's splitting at each space until it finds a matching exe.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Aaarh I guess that makes sense - so due to the spaces in the main application name, a single pair of double quotes is not enough in the ```sc.exe create``` command? Still seems very interesting, as the service has been given the full binpath to the actual executable that it should run on startup - but I can't find any documentation for the splitting approach.